# Difference between * and ? in Spring @Scheduled(cron=".....")

Tags: java, spring, cron, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I've been looking at the Spring Boot example for scheduling tasks (https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/) and reading through some documentation (https://javahunter.wordpress.com/2011/05/05/cronscheduler-in-spring/) and I see that * and ? are used almost interchangeably.

For example, the line

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 15 10 ? * *")
```

and

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 15 10 * * ?")
```

do the exact same thing. So what is the difference between * and ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

asterix stands for all possible values. question marks should be used for non specific value

> *("all values") - used to select all values within a field. For example, "" in the minute field means *"every minute".
>
> ? ("no specific value") - useful when you need to specify something in
> one of the two fields in which the character is allowed, but not the
> other. For example, if I want my trigger to fire on a particular day
> of the month (say, the 10th), but don't care what day of the week that
> happens to be, I would put "10" in the day-of-month field, and "?" in
> the day-of-week field. See the examples below for clarification.

Copied from the [tutorial](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger)

Comment: Sorry, but no :(. `?` is **exactly** the same than `*` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30341067/difference-between-and-in-spring-scheduledcron/30789834#30789834

Comment: Because that's the way it is implemented :(. Sad, but true: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30341067/difference-between-and-in-spring-scheduledcron/30341102

Comment: @Luchostein it is the same  for implenetation. But in case of documentation it is different

Comment: You'll have to deal with the bug regardless of what the documentation says.

Comment: According to this specification, "0 15 10 * * Fri" is supposed to never be executed because it means at the same time "any day of the month" (precisely that) AND Friday?

Comment: On the other hand, what does "0 15 10 13 * Fri" mean? Is it for Fri 13th? If so, then * * Fri is just equal to ? * Fri and I fail to see any reason for introducing "?" at all. Oh, that's it: "Support for specifying both a day-of-week and a day-of-month value is not complete (you must currently use the ‘?’ character in one of these fields)." - so the meaning of such an expression is not yet defined.

Comment: I also know how to read the documentation, but this gave absolutely no understanding of the difference between * and?

Answer (score 43):

The tutorial is outdated. The symbol `?` means **exactly** the same as the symbol `*`.

As of Spring version *3.1.2.RELEASE*, the call hierarchy is the following:

1. The constructor `CronTrigger(String)` calls the constructor `CronSequenceGenerator(String)`
2. `CronSequenceGenerator(String)` calls `parse(String)`
3. `parse(String)` calls `setDays(BitSet bits, String field, int max)`.

Its implementation is clear:

```java
private void setDays(BitSet bits, String field, int max) {
    if (field.contains("?")) {
        field = "*";
    }
    setNumberHits(bits, field, 0, max);
}
```

So, if `?`, then `*`.

Comment: Are you sure? '?' is still mentioned in the documentation http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html

Comment: That's exactly the problem. The documentation says so, but the code doesn't.

Comment: It's not really a bug, implementation of dealing with * and ? are the same, but in terms of your configuration intent they are slightly different.

Comment: This is still true as of Spring 4.3.X. The setDays method that performs this replacement is only used on the 4th (days of month) and 6th (days of week) fields.

Comment: Why not a bug? See my example "0 15 10 * * Fri" here, looks like it should not match anything but with this implemenation, ? and * are treated equivalently (presumably as "do not look at this field at all", not "allow every value")